# How can you efficiently flip a large range of indices's values from 1 to 0 or vice versa

Tags: algorithm

You're given an N sized array `arr`. Suppose there's a contiguous interval `arr[a....b]` where you want to flip all the 1s to 0s and vice versa. Now suppose that there are a large (millions or billions) of these intervals (they could have different starting and end points) that you need to process. Is there an efficient algorithm to get this done?

Note that `a` and `b` are inclusive. `N` can be any finite size essentially. The purpose of the question was just to practice algorithms.

Consider `arr = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0]`

Consider that we want to flips the following inclusive intervals `[1,3], [0,4]`

After process `[1,3]`, we have `arr = [0,1,1,1,0,0,0]` and after processing `[0,4]`, we have `arr = [1,0,0,0,1,0,0]`, which is the final array.

Comment: What do you need this for? How large is N? Show an example? Do you only need the end result, or be able to read array values between the modifications? Have you tried the straightforward marking of all flip points and building the end result with one pass from that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The obvious efficient way to do that is to *not* do that. Instead first collect at what indices the flipping changes, and then do one pass to apply the collected flipping information.

Python implementation of a naive solution, the efficient solution, and testing:

```
def naive(arr, intervals):
    for a, b in intervals:
        for i in range(a, b+1):
            arr[i] ^= 1

def efficient(arr, intervals):
    flips = [0] * len(arr)
    for a, b in intervals:
        flips[a] ^= 1
        flips[b+1] ^= 1
    xor = 0
    for i, flip in enumerate(flips):
        xor ^= flip
        arr[i] ^= xor

def test():
    import random
    n = 30
    arr = random.choices([0, 1], k=n)
    intervals = []
    while len(intervals) < 100:
        a = random.randrange(n-1)
        b = random.randrange(n-1)
        if a <= b:
            intervals.append((a, b))

    print(f'{arr =    }')

    expect = arr * 1
    naive(expect, intervals)
    print(f'{expect = }')

    result = arr * 1
    efficient(result, intervals)
    print(f'{result = }')

    print(f'{(result == expect) = }')

test()
```

Demo output:

```
arr =    [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
expect = [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
result = [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
(result == expect) = True
```

Comment: I had a similar idea, but I used prefix sums instead of XOR. Also is your `b` inclusive? If so, shouldn't all your b's be b+1? It looks your algorithm is assuming `b` isn't inclusive.

Comment: No, it's exclusive. Your question is unclear about that, that's one reason I asked for an example.

Comment: Just added some clarification in the OP. Sorry about that. You asked me "how large is N." Would you answer change for small N vs large N?

Comment: @user5965026 Ok, I adjusted the answer accordingly. Next time please don't just dump a question and then walk away for hours. Stick around and react to comments in timely fashion. For *very* large N, maybe in the trilllions, or in general if N is much larger than the number of intervals, I might make my `flips` some sparse data structure instead of a list of size N, or (ab)use `arr` for it (like with `arr[a] ^= 2` instead of `flips[a] ^= 1`). Trillions seems unrealistic, but so do billions of intervals, so what do I know :-)

Answer (score 0):

Cast to Int Array and use bitwise not if you are using C or C++. But this is an SIMD task so its parallelizable if you wish.

Comment: They asked for an efficient algorithm. This sounds like brute force.